# Error in Pie Register plugin Got both side message

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to place 3 forms in my wordpress theme, but I get the following message when a user registers or logs in:

> "Thank you for your registration".

My demo site is at:    http://evasoft.in/

I am using the [pie-register plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pie-register/).

I use the following shortcode for the login form:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[pie_register_login]'); ?>
```

And for the registration form:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[pie_register_form]'); ?>
```

I also want to send a confirmation email to the user, but that is not working.

Comment: Try to put both in different pages and see the output . //Just for the debugging purpose.

Comment: yes if i try to put both in different page it's working but 
user does't receive confirmation email :( ??

Comment: Have you done the setting for confirmation email in the backend?

Comment: yes already 
but not working i got many fake email everyday
help me for solve this

Comment: Sorry..But can't help without code access.